# Is there a term for the dimension of the annihilator of an element of an algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, terminology

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a finite dimensional $R$-algebra, and for $x \in \mathcal{A}$ consider $\mathrm{Ann}(x) = \{ c \in \mathcal{A} \mid cx = 0 \}$. Is there a term for the dimension of this subspace?

For example, if $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{R}[j]/ \langle j^2-1 \rangle $, $\mathrm{Ann}(j+1) = \mathrm{span}\{ j - 1\}$, so $\dim(\mathrm{Ann}(j+1)) = 1$.

Comment: I've never seen such a term. Why do you need a term to dress up "dimension of $Ann(x)$?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm studying the structure of zero divisors in finite dimensional real associative algebras, and found this specific notion useful in my research, so I was wondering if there was already an established term for it or not.